# Appengine datastore Row count on an entity using GQL

Tags: google-app-engine, gql

Is there a way to get total number of rows in a Google App Engine Datastore Table (Entity) using GQL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use count.  It is in the doc: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlqueryclass?hl=nl#GqlQuery_count

Comment: Does this work from the Datastore Viewer GQL command ? I am looking for that. But this helps, nonetheless. Thanks !

Comment: NO, you cannot chain methods in the Datastore viewer